# I installed 3.11.4 in python but anaconda prompt shows 3.10.11 - why and should I upgrade in anaconda?

Tags: anaconda3, python-3.11

Do I need to upgrade within anaconda itself ?

Why does it show 3.10.11 under anaconda?
Should it show the latest version I installed ?

If yes what do I need to do to upgrade it within anaconda?

Do they both should match or it does not matter?